# Already complete scraping scrapes everything on the page. I would like to limit the scraping to only a certain section

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I placed the code of a complete and properly functioning scraping that I own. Successfully scrapes all elements on the page.

However, I would like to scrape only a small limited section of the page with the same elements as scraping. This limited section is already scraped correctly along with all elements of the page, but I would like to scrape only it and not "all + it". The link is [here](https://www.diretta.it/calcio/germania/bundesliga/)

There are 4 tables on the page, but I would like to scrape just one, that is the table called "Programma", ie the html section **"event-summary event"** or **"leagues-static event-summary-leagues "**. But of this section only the elements of the last round (Matchday 14). Matchday 14 only. No round 15. So obviously that with each update of the page rounds, the last round is always scraped as well.

So I would need to insert something that makes scraping understand to download only the elements (which it already owns and scrapes) of of that section and the last round.

The code is already complete and works fine, so I'm not looking for code services, but for a little hint to tell me how to limit the scraping to just the section mentioned above. Scraping is in Selenium. I would like to stick with Selenium and my code as it is already functional and complete. Thanks

[image]

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")
driver.implicitly_wait(12)
#driver.minimize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


all_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='event__round'],div[class^='event__match']")

current_round = '?'

for bundesliga in all_rows:
    classes = bundesliga.get_attribute('class')
    #print(classes)

    if 'event__round' in classes:
        #round = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__round event__round--static']")
        #current_round = row.text  # full text `Round 20`

        current_round = bundesliga.text.split(" ")[-1]  # only `20` without `Round`   
                
    else:       
        datetime = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__time']")

        #Divide la data e l'ora
        date, time = datetime.text.split(" ")
        date = date.rstrip('.')  # right-strip to remove `.` at the end of date

        
        team_home = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__participant event__participant--home']")            
        team_away = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__participant event__participant--away']")
        score_home = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--home']")
        score_away = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--away']")
        
 
        bundesliga = [current_round, date, time, team_home.text, team_away.text, score_home.text, score_away.text]
        bundesliga.append(bundesliga)
        print(bundesliga)
```

Comment: Still can't find the _the html section "event-summary event" or "leagues-static event-summary-leagues "_

Comment: @DebanjanB  Go where it says "Programma". The table where it says Programma and Giornata 14. Look my screenshot https://pasteboard.co/Fj4qU7AMmZnk.jpg

Comment: Yeah, now can find `event event--summary` class. So you only want to scrape the last rounds.

Comment: @DebanjanB  Yes, the last round in the "Programma" (the one with no results, therefore the one still to be played). But it also says Round 15, I don't want 15. Only the 14. So obviously with every round update on the page, I would just scrape the last round. The elements are the same as I have in scraping. Thanks :)

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room in a few minutes.

Comment: @DebanjanB  Why do we have to talk about it elsewhere? If you can help me you can write me here, otherwise it doesn't matter :) Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is limit `all_rows` variable. One way to do this is finding the tab you are looking for with text and then getting the parent elements.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.someurl/some/other/page")
driver.implicitly_wait(12)
#driver.minimize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


# all_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='event__round'],div[class^='event__match']")
############### UPDATE ####################
def parent_element(element):
    return element.find_element(By.XPATH, './..')
programma_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Programma']")))

programma_element_p1 = parent_element(programma_element)
programma_element_p2 = parent_element(programma_element_p1)
programma_element_p3 = parent_element(programma_element_p2)

all_rows = programma_element_p3.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='event__round'],div[class^='event__match']")
filter_rows = []

for row in all_rows:
    if "event__match--last" in row.get_attribute('class'):
        filter_rows.append(row)
        break
    else:
        filter_rows.append(row)

############### UPDATE ####################
current_round = '?'

for bundesliga in filter_rows:
    classes = bundesliga.get_attribute('class')
    #print(classes)

    if 'event__round' in classes:
        #round = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__round event__round--static']")
        #current_round = row.text  # full text `Round 20`

        current_round = bundesliga.text.split(" ")[-1]  # only `20` without `Round`   
                
    else:       
        datetime = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__time']")

        #Divide la data e l'ora
        date, time = datetime.text.split(" ")
        date = date.rstrip('.')  # right-strip to remove `.` at the end of date

        
        team_home = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__participant event__participant--home']")            
        team_away = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__participant event__participant--away']")
        # score_home = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--home']")
        # score_away = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--away']")

        try:
            score_home = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--home']")
        except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException):
            MyObject = type('MyObject', (object,), {})
            score_home = MyObject()
            score_home.text = "-"
        try:
            score_away = bundesliga.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--away']")
        except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException):
            MyObject = type('MyObject', (object,), {})
            score_away = MyObject()
            score_away.text = "-"
        
 
        bundesliga = [current_round, date, time, team_home.text, team_away.text, score_home.text, score_away.text]
        bundesliga.append(bundesliga)
        print(bundesliga)
```

Comment: I have found that your code, extraordinary as it is, scrapes both round 14 and round 15. In fact, I noticed the Cologne-Augusta match which is in 15. Yours was probably a distraction. As you saw in the question I highlight with the red color that I would like to scrape only round 14. I would like to solve it by myself, but I am not able to do it since I am a beginner in Python. Could you correct your answer please? You are great!

Comment: @Johan.D. just to confirm you want to exclude round 15 temporarily and then include it when round 15 and round 16 are in the table?

Comment: @Johan.D. added some more updates

Comment: I get an error: except TimeoutException: NameError: TimeoutException is not defined. I confirm that I want to exclude round 15. I don't understand what you mean by "and then include it when round 15 and round 16 are in the table". After a few days the web page will be updated and round 14 will be gone, so then I would like to scrape the next round which will be 15 (only 15, but not round 16).Now I would like to scrape only the 14 but not the 15. After update,next week I would like to scrape only the 15 but not the 16. Then again I would like to scrape the 16 but not the 17, and so on.

Comment: @Johan.D. thanks for confirming, I updated the answer to include the import for the `TimeoutException`.

Comment: Thanks to you, but now I get another error. Also I had tried to import TimeoutException. Now with your code I get this: raise exception_class (message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [class ^ = 'event__score event__score - home']
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError @ chrome: //remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm: 181: 5
NoSuchElementError @ chrome: //remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm: 393: 5
element.find / </ <@chrome: //remote/content/marionette/element.js: 299: 16

Comment: The  Try/Except section lets the variable "score_home" and "score_away" set  the ".text" to a value of "-" when the css selector is not found.  Which turns out to be all the places where a "Preview" link is found.

Comment: Voted and set the question as resolved thanks to you. Thanks.